# I am not getting any messages when I return a value in a simple C program. How can I resolve this?

Tags: c

I was wondering why the following program can be compiled in gcc, but when i use ./abs (the name of the script) no output would be given.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double AbsoluteValue(double x)
{
    if (x > 0)
    {
        return x;
    }
    else if (x < 0)
    {
        return -x;
    }
}

int main (void)
{
    AbsoluteValue(2.00);
}
```

Comment: Because you never output anything in the code?

Comment: How about using [printf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) to print the value returned from `AbsoluteValue` and then append a `return 0` to return gracefully from main.

Comment: You should make a minimal effort to understand what you are trying to achieve (output) and the means you intend to use (C with the standard library). Clearly you haven't read any introductory material, neither online nor offline, and yet you ask us for help and waste our time.

Comment: You're not printing anything anyway..

Comment: The book I used didn't say I had to do so. I thought I just had to call the function within main().

Comment: You should get into the habit of compiling with `-Wall` and `-pedantic` flags, because the compiler should warn you that the `main` function isn't returning an int. Also: `printf`...

Answer (score 4):

There's no output because the code doesn't print anything. Change your `main` to:

```
int main (void)
{
    double d;

    d = AbsoluteValue(2.00);
    printf("%f\n", d);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The book I'm using isn't very clear on how to use the return value.

Comment: Not a problem. Learning C can be a tough crawl. Best of luck.

Comment: @Justin: maybe should through away your book and get another one.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't give any command to print and also you should use some double variable in main function to store return value from AbsoluteValue() method.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double AbsoluteValue(double x)
{
if (x > 0)
{
    return x;
}
else if (x < 0)
{
    return -x;
}
}

int main (void)
{
double rtrn;
rtrn=AbsoluteValue(2.00);
printf("%f",rtrn);
}
```